# mobidata MBD-100EU USB EDGE modem on Ubuntu 9.04 OS

Tags: ubuntu, usb, modem, ubuntu-9.04

I can not use my mobidata MBD-100EU USB EDGE modem in my Ubuntu 9.04 OS. I am trying to use it and tried in different ways. Can anyone help me (giving instruction) to install and use this modem.

Answer (score 1):

You may be out of luck. There is an open bug report describing the problem: [**Mobidata EDGE modem issue with Linux Kernel (cp2101.c)**](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/387748). The fix should be in the 2.6.31 kernel, so it might be a short wait. [This post](http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/wireless-internet/148376-mobidata-edge-modem-issue-linux-kernel-cp2101-c.html) also discusses the same issue, and additionally has instructions on compiling the kernel yourself if interested.